# Proving associativity over elements of Reals

Tags: vector-spaces, axioms

[image]

My question has to do with the exercise above. I am to prove that the following set is a vector space. When I come across Axiom 3, the associative property, a necessary property of the set to be a vector space, I basically arrive at something like this:

I'm going to define $3$ polynomials $u, v,$ and $w$ such that:

$$u = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$$$$v= b_{0} + b_{1}x + b_{2}x^2$$

$$w= c_{0}+c_{1}x+c_{2}x^2$$

For $P_2$ to be a vector space, the following must be true:

$$u + (v+w) = (u+v)+w$$

However.. the only way I can prove it is by plugging in my expressions for $u, v$ and $w$ and just stating that the following are equivalent because.. they are. That's just how Real numbers behave. Is there something I can do to prove it other than just saying, well, $P_2$ is a subset of real numbers and due to this have this associative property? Is there anything else I can do, or leave it at that?

Comment: But $u$, $v$, and $w$ aren't real numbers; they are polynomials with real coefficients.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Right, so how do I prove associativity then here?

Comment: By collecting coefficients.  At that point, invoke the associative property for addition of real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will show you how to write a proof of something seemingly obvious. You just need to be a little careful that you do not make loose statements. One such made in your question was "$P_2$ is a subset of the real numbers", which is definitely not true.

1 : Note that $$(u+v)+w = ((a_0 + b_0) + c_0) + ((a_1 + b_1) + c_1)x + ((a_2 + b_2) + c_2)x^2 \tag{def'n}$$ by definition of how we add polynomials.

2 : By associativity of addition of real numbers (we do not need to prove this), we see that:$$
(a_i + b_i) + c_i = a_i + (b_i + c_i) \quad ;\quad i = 0,1,2 \tag{assoc}
$$

3: Substituting $(\mathrm {assoc})$ in $(\mathrm{def'n})$ gives us:
$$
((a_0 + b_0) + c_0) + ((a_1 + b_1) + c_1)x + ((a_2 + b_2) + c_2)x^2 \\ =(a_0 +( b_0 + c_0)) + (a_1 + (b_1 + c_1))x + (a_2 + (b_2 + c_2))x^2 \tag{3}
$$

4 : Finally, from definition, we observe that:
$$
u + (v + w) = (a_0 +( b_0 + c_0)) + (a_1 + (b_1 + c_1))x + (a_2 + (b_2 + c_2))x^2 =^{3}(u + v) + w
$$

which completes the proof of associativity of addition of polynomials.